# Looking to reduce postgres queries to one query

Tags: postgresql

I want to reduce the number of queries I'm making to my postgres database.

Currently I have this

```
select * from token_balances where asset_id = '36f813e4-403a-4246-a405-8efc0cbde76a' AND tick < yesterday ORDER BY tick DESC LIMIT 1;
select * from token_balances where asset_id = '36f813e4-403a-4246-a405-8efc0cbde76a' AND tick < last_week ORDER BY tick DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is there some way I can make this into one query. Or is there even any need to reduce it?

Thanks

Comment: This is the same query twice, what do you mean to make this into one query?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. One of the dates it for yesterdays date and the other is one week.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the query with the greater date of `tick`. **The first query already includes the results coming from the second one**.

**Just use the first query and you are good to go.**

```sql
select * from token_balances where asset_id = '36f813e4-403a-4246-a405-8efc0cbde76a' AND tick < '2022-05-26T14:13:42.914Z' ORDER BY tick DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I want to get two results. One row needs to be where the tick was yesterday and the second needs to be where the tick was last week. I've edited my question slightly

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `yesterday` (which is a valid reference) and `last_week` (which is not valid) just convert to date arithmetic. You can use simple date subtraction:

```
select * 
  from token_balances 
 where asset_id = '36f813e4-403a-4246-a405-8efc0cbde76a' 
   and tick < current_date - :num_days
 order by tick desc
 limit 1;
```